# How can I make GEP work on my Eclipse Juno?

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I'm currently trying to install Google Eclipse Plugin on my Eclipse Juno (on Windows 7, , with JRE 1.5.22u and with the Java EE IDE). I've read the google doc available [here](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download) and tried to install with and without admin mode. Installation seems to work well but I am still not able to find any google feature (toolbar, google web application, ...).

Am i doing something wrong ?

Cheers,

Ricola3D

Comment: I had successfully done it on Eclipse Classic but it was not functional i.e it didnt behave the way it was supposed to.